# Rails with Docker 'Could not find ... in any of the sources' for an existing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

My rails application runs using a docker and everytime I try to execute any 'bin/rails' commands in the terminal of the docker container, it raises the following error

```rb
Could not find racc-1.6.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

on executing 'gem list' I have checked that racc is installed as 'racc (1.6.0 default: 1.5.1)' and calling 'bundle install' as the app suggest raises the same error. I assumed that maybe the 'default: 1.5.1' is the problem but did not manage to come around this one so far. Also executing 'which racc' or 'bundle info racc' returns the correct version of racc which is 1.6.0.

Update:

an exception is 'bin/rails server' which means the application launches like usual but I cannot do migrations and console calls.
Trying to use other racc version did not do any better since using 1.5.2 raises the same error and 1.5.1 requires nokogiri-linux which I did not manage to install locally so far

Comment: I could usually run the commands but at some point this error occurred and I am basically re-deploying the dockerfile right now to see where the problem is

Comment: I would like to have more information. How is bundle configuration? Are you using `vendor/bundle` to store the gems?

Comment: @AjayBarot Sorry I am not really good with the bundler but on my projects directory I found a ```vendor/cache``` folder where all the .gem files are stored, is that the right one?

Comment: Ok no problem. Can you please let us know the version of `bundler` you are using? `bundler -v`. Please make sure you are using the same bundler for your local and server.

Comment: @AjayBarot It is using bundler 2.2.3 on both local and docker. I also realized that the remote interpreter of my rails app (the docker container) lists several versions of racc (1.6.0, 1.5.2 and one that just says 'racc'). May this cause a confusion when the app tries to find the gems?

Comment: By any chance can we have more error logs of `bundle install`.  `mkmf.log` will also work. you can get the mkmf.log by doing this `find ~/.rvm -name mkmf.log
`

Comment: that can be an issue. Let me know if you need more help. We can have a discussion in chat.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you shared the `Gemfile` and the `Dockerfile`. You may need to rebuild the docker container without the cache, with something like `docker build . --no-cache`

Answer (score 2):

please try “docker-compose run web bundle install” command. This should work

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately building an image using the given docker-compose command raises the same error which is odd, since the rails-app seems to find every gem correctly except "racc-1.6.0"

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying a bunch of commands and re-deploying the image I figured out that in the end **creating a new project** would solve most of the issues. Unfortunately, I still did not find out the cause of this problem but I assume there might have been conflicts in the configuration or general problems in the project setting. So heres the solution summed up

Solution 1:

- create a new rails project and make sure it has **identical** gem requirement as the original project (simple way of doing this is to copy/paste the content of gemfile from the original project)
- run new project application and check if `bin/rails console` (optional)
- copy the entire content of the new project into the original project (don't forget to back up original project before doing so)

Solution 2:

- if your project directory has a hidden `.bundle` folder, delete it to prevent rails app from reading gems in `vendor/cache`. Check `bundle info <gem-name>` to see if gem path is set on the correct gem-directory

Probably not a solution for all cause but this was my last option to try when everything else failed